# How to get screensize of Android WebView from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, webview, window, screen-size

I need to create an Android app which opens a webview.  In the webview, I'm trying to adjust  image's size within the page, using JavaScript.

The problem is that I can't find a way to reliably detect the width of the screen.

window.innerWidth or outerWidth almost works, but randomly returns a wrong value on the same device.

Is there any other good way to detect width of the screen?

Comment: Have you read: http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

that`s get display dimensions in pixels

**Edit:**

or you can use this code :

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

Answer (score -1):

Try [addJavaScriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)

By doing so, you can communicate with your native code and javascript in webview. in the native code, write a function to get the webvew's width, and call this function from javascript by implementing JavaScriptInterface.

Comment: there's no answer here; could you specify how to write the native function to get the WebView's width?